# How to get message sent date in webhook whatsapp API

Tags: webhooks, whatsapp

how to get message sent date. The timestamp of the message that arrives in the whatsapp API webhook is the date on which it arrives. I need to retrieve date the user sent. It's possible?

In the message model I receive, in this format in the webhook, the timestamp is the time it arrives on the server. I need to retrieve the time the user sent the message, in case he is offline

```json
{
    "object": "whatsapp_business_account",
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": "8856996819413533",
            "changes": [
                {
                    "value": {
                        "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
                        "metadata": {
                            "display_phone_number": "16505553333",
                            "phone_number_id": "27681414235104944"
                        },
                        "contacts": [
                            {
                                "profile": {
                                    "name": "Kerry Fisher"
                                },
                                "wa_id": "16315551234"
                            }
                        ],
                        "messages": [
                            {
                                "from": "16315551234",
                                "id": "wamid.ABGGFlCGg0cvAgo-sJQh43L5Pe4W",
                                "timestamp": "1603059201",
                                "text": {
                                    "body": "Hello this is an answer"
                                },
                                "type": "text"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "field": "messages"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried sending other types of messages, and even monitoring all dates that are sent to the webhook. But none match the user's upload date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is only one timestamp in message payload, that is,

> *The time when the WhatsApp server received the message from the customer.*

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/webhooks/components#messages-object